# Convert json to xml in worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a very strange requirement in which I need to convert JSON to XML in worklight server's adapter procedure and then need to send that xml to some other systems.

I am using HTTP worklight adapter.

Is it possible to overcome this requirement in worklight adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer after googling a lot.

Worklight has flexibility to use java code.

I had already java code ready which serves the purpose(convert json to xml) so i just imported that class in my worklight project(copy in apps/server/ folder).

In adapter i have used that class like `var xml = com.XXXX.json2xml(input);`

Deploy adapter and worklight application war file and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

If having 3rd party library support in adapters is important to you, please open a [Request for Enhancement (RFE)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe&BRAND_ID=181&PROD_FAM_ID=341&PROD_ID=702&PRESELECT_DROPDOWNS=true).